# I can not fix my class and for loop

Tags: python, class

```
           class Conjugaison:
                  def Simple_Present(self):
                           self.group =  {"Je":'e', "Tu":'es', "Il ou 
                  Elles":'e' , "Nous":'ons' ,"Vous":'ez' ,"Ils ou Elles":'ent'}

                            self.verb = str(input("Enter a veb here:"))
                            for keys in self.group:
                                 print(keys,self.verb[:-2]+self.group(keys))
            Em1 = Conjugason()
            Em1.Simple_Present()
```

When I runed this code above that is what I am getting:

```
                                Enter a verb here: entrer

                                        Vous entrez
                                        Tu entres
                                        Ils ou Elles entrent
                                        Il ou Elles entre
                                        Nous entrons
                                        Je entre
```

I was expected something like this:
                                            Je entre.....
                                            tu entres....
                                            il ou elle entre.....
                                            nous entrons.....
                                            vous entrez......
                                            ils ou elles entrent.

I do not know where I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Not that should matter logically, but we are humans and not computers, so it would help if you translated the text.

Comment: My french is very weak...

Comment: you are defining some other class and calling some other class...

Answer (score 0):

here the classname is  'Conjugaison'
 But the object you created here is 'Conjugason'
 Em1 = Conjugason()

calling different class than the one created.

Answer (score 0):

I see that people are not answering the actual question you were asking.
Of course the class you call has a typo `Conjugason` instead of `Conjugaison`, but it does not produce any error here.

But you are complaining that the printing order is not correct.
Well, in Python, the standard dictionaries are not ordered.

I would suggest you use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). With this, your for loop will follow the order you defined when creating the dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class Conjugaison:
    def Simple_Present(self):
        self.group = OrderedDict([("Je", "e"), ("Tu", "es"), ("Il ou Elle", "e"),
                                  ("Nous", "ons"), ("Vous", "ez"), 
                                  ("Ils ou Elles", 'ent')])

        self.verb = str(input("Enter a verb here:"))
        for keys in self.group:
            print(keys,self.verb[:-2]+self.group(keys))


Em1 = Conjugaison()
Em1.Simple_Present()
```

PS : I am french, you can add an extra logic. If your verb starts with a vowel, you need to use `J'` instead of `Je`.
And for the singular 3rd person, it would be `Il ou Elle` instead of `Il ou Elles`.
There is no real need of a class here yet, you could just call your function outside of the class.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You understood my issue. I think next time I will to make it clear for everyone.

Comment: Was this answer helpful to your case ? are you using OrderedDict to keep the pronoun order ?

Comment: I am glad it did !
Could you please validate the answer for other people to find the help they might search coming to this post. 
It is below the point counter of this answer. A "V" tick to press.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is an `unordered` associative table.
This means that you cannot rely on the order of the key-value pairs when you iterate through it with a for-each loop. It's not an error on your part, it's the designed behaviour for dictionaries.

You can have a list of keys, that will keep the order you like for outputs:

```
subjects = ['Je', 'Tu', 'Il ou Elle', 'Nous', 'Vous', 'Ils ou Elles']
terminaisons = ['e', 'es', 'e', 'ons', 'ez', 'ent']
for subject, terminaison in zip(subjects, terminaisons):
    print(subject, terminaison)
```

This doesn't make use of a dictionary though.
If you want to play and test a dictionary, you can write the following:

```
conjugaisonTable = {subject: terminaison for subject, terminaison in zip(subjects, terminaisons)}
for subject in subjects:
    print(subject, conjugaisonTable[subject])
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint. It is much better and easier to use List. Thank you!